# How to tell the memory usage of each background job

Tags: background-process, jobs, gridengine

I am working on SGE, and I am logged on to it. I use qlogin -l mf=30G so as to get onto one compute node.

I am running 2 jobs on this compute node in the background.

```
[1]   4408 Running                 /apps1/sratoolkit/2.3.5-2/bin/fastq-dump --split-files SRR1660.sra &
[2]   4415 Running                 /apps1/sratoolkit/2.3.5-2/bin/fastq-dump --split-files SRR1661.sra &
```

I want to know how much memory each of my background jobs is consuming out of 30G i assigned in the beginning. Any command to find that out??

Thanks

Comment: I would try `ps -l -p 4408,4415` then look at vsz or similar ressources.

Answer (score 1):

**4408** and **4415** are the processe's PIDs. Use *top* or similar utility to see cpu and memory usage.

Comment: Isn't `top` a bit too tedious for such task? One could execute `ps aux` and pipe the output to the `grep`. Like: `ps aux | grep '4408\|4415'`

Comment: @cnduo I think is the other way around. Cause top would update the process usage automatically, since the application would variate it's resources demand. ps would give a snapshot value.